# Get a value from sql file to the invoking sql file

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I have a `file1.sql` which invokes `file2.sql`.

file2.sql:

```
declare
v_stmt varchar2(1000);
begin
v_stmt := 'create index idx on tab1(&1)';
:stmt  := v_stmt;
end;
/
```

file1.sql:

```
var stmt varchar2(4000);
@file2.sql 'col1'
:stmt;
```

Executing `file1.sql` throws the following errors:

```
SP2-0552: Bind variable "STMT" not declared.  
SP2-0042: unknown command ":stmt" - rest of line ignored.
```

How do I get the value of variable `v_stmt` in `file1.sql`?

Comment: You shouldn't be getting the SP2-0552 from what you've shown, that bind variable does exist and is being populated. I don't see that when I create and run both files as you've shown them.

Answer (score 1):

You can't run arbitrary code from the SQL*Plus command line using a bind variable; the bind variable is relevant to SQL and PL/SQL statements, not natively to SQL*Plus (even though it's declared there with the `var`).

To execute the statement you'll need to use dynamic SQL, in an anonymous PL/SQL block; so changing `file1.sql` to:

```
var stmt varchar2(4000);
@file2.sql 'col1'

begin
  execute immediate :stmt;
end;
/
```

or slightly shorter, but also perhaps slightly confusing::

```
var stmt varchar2(4000);
@file2.sql 'col1'
exec execute immediate :stmt;
```

When I run that I see:

```
SQL> @file1

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

begin
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
ORA-06512: at line 2
```

which is reasonable as I don't have your `tab1` table in my schema. You can see that is trying to execute the statement though; and there is no SP2-0552 error (though I don't see that with your original code either).

You can also use `print stmt` to see the generated value before it's run (note there is no colon prefix); or you could use `dbms_output` within the anonymous block, of course.